# Relatve and Absolute path in JQUERY Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
$.ajax(
      {
    type: "GET",                    
    url: 'Home/GetMsg',                 
    success: function (result) {        },
    error: function (req, status, error) {}
     });
```

By Default URL taking relative path for Home/GetMsg. I am calling this function from different controller/view which disturb the URL.
How can i mention absolute and relative path here. i did tried with 
URL: 'http://abc.com/Home/Getmsg' but again its not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a helper:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetMsg", "Home")',
```

or if this is in a separate javascript file where you cannot use server side helpers, you could use helpers to generate the url on some existing DOM element using HTML5 data-* attributes:

```
<div id="foo" data-url="@Url.Action("GetMsg", "Home")">Foo</div>
```

and then in your js:

```
url: $('#foo').data('url'),
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using MVC, you may be looking for **[Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx)** helper:

```
@Url.Action("GetMsg","Home")
```

Also, if you are going to be using paths within Javascript, it may be a good idea to use hidden elements with the path so that you can use the Javascript externally, for example:

```
@Html.Hidden("GetMsgPath",Url.Action("GetMsg","Home"))

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",                    
    url: $("#GetMsgPath").val(),                 
    success: function (result) {        },
    error: function (req, status, error) {}
});
```